# Swiper slider instance not working after slide run

Tags: carousel, swiper.js, elementor

I added the below codes in my WordPress footer it's working fine on load but after the first slide, the instance not working. Where I missed?

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
            const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
                centeredSlides: true,
                spaceBetween:20,
                slidesPerView:2,
                loop: true,
            });
    }); 
});
```